# postgres regexp_matches not returning all the matches

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
  <itemBody>
    <gapMatchInteraction responseIdentifier="RESPONSE2" shuffle="false" hideprompt="true" emptyquestion="false" maxChoices="1" orientation="horizontal" gapmatchpersistentheader="inherit" required="true" mappedValue="">
      <prompt>
        <p>Add question here.</p>
      </prompt>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceA" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text A</p>
      </gapText>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceB" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text B</p>
      </gapText>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceC" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text C</p>
      </gapText>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceD" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text D</p>
      </gapText>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceE" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text E</p>
      </gapText>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceF" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text E</p>
      </gapText>
      <blockquote>
        <p>Some text <gap identifier="G1" width="" modified="true" label="GAP 1"><p>GAP 1</p></gap>
<gap identifier="G2" width="" modified="true" label="GAP 2"><p>GAP 2</p></gap><gap identifier="G3" width="" modified="true" label="Gap 3"><p>Gap 3</p></gap><gap identifier="G4" width="" modified="true" label="Gap 4"><p>Gap 4</p></gap></p>
      </blockquote>
    </gapMatchInteraction>
    <gapMatchInteraction responseIdentifier="RESPONSE3" shuffle="false" hideprompt="true" emptyquestion="false" maxChoices="1" orientation="horizontal" gapmatchpersistentheader="inherit" required="true" mappedValue="">
      <prompt>
        <p>Add question here.</p>
      </prompt>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceA" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text A</p>
      </gapText>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceB" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text B</p>
      </gapText>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceC" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text C</p>
      </gapText>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceD" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text D</p>
      </gapText>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceE" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text E</p>
      </gapText>
      <gapText identifier="ChoiceF" width="" matchMin="0" matchMax="0">
        <p>Text E</p>
      </gapText>
      <blockquote>
        <p>Some text <gap identifier="G1" width="" modified="true" label="GAP 1"><p>GAP 1</p></gap><gap identifier="G2" width="" modified="true" label="GAP 2"><p>GAP 2</p></gap><gap identifier="G3" width="" modified="true" label="Gap 3"><p>Gap 3</p></gap></p>
      </blockquote>
    </gapMatchInteraction>
  </itemBody>
```

I want to find all the occurrences of

`gapMatchInteraction` with `responseIdentifier="RESPONSE2"` and `gap` with `identifier="G1"`

(i.e., just the bold part), in sequence - that is RESPONSE2, G1, G2, G3, G4, RESPONSE3, G1, G2, G3.

This is what my regular expression string is:

```
(?:<gapMatchInteraction responseIdentifier="(RESPONSE\w)".+?)?<gap identifier="(\w+?)"
```

I tested this online(https://regex101.com/) and it matches all the occurrences, in sequence.

The problem is, when I use this in the PostgreSQL `regexp_matches` function, I only get `[RESPONSE2,G3]`. This is my query:

```
select regexp_matches(column_name, '(?:<gapMatchInteraction responseIdentifier="(RESPONSE\w)".+?)?<gap identifier="(\w+?)"','gis') 
from my_table
```

Not sure what the problem is. Any help would be much much appreciated.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? XML functions are a much better choice for processing XML than regex

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I am using version 10.3.
The column is stored as text in db instead of xml type

Comment: You can cast it to `xml`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `xmltable()` for that rather than regex:

```
select x.*
from the_table,
    xmltable ('//gapMatchInteraction[@responseIdentifier="RESPONSE2"]//gap[@identifier="G2"]'
      passing cast(column_name as xml)
      COLUMNS 
        id text path '@identifier',
        width text path '@width',
        modified boolean path '@modified',
        label text path '@label',
        content xml path './*'
  ) as x
;
```

returns

```
id | width | modified | label | content     
---+-------+----------+-------+-------------
G2 |       | true     | GAP 2 | <p>GAP 2</p>
```

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b45869d8b6bc0292f36e7035194de490